# Batch insertion of Rows

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uikit

i read about Batch insertion and deletion of rows in the apple documentation,but didnt get a clear idea of it's use.
For example can i use it to add a few rows(animated) when the user taps on a row in the table,like a drop down list??Can somebody explain it to me or give a reference as to where i can find a tutorial??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was pretty easy,Figured this one out on my own.All that i had to to do was modify the array from which the cells got their content,just before inserting the rows as explained in Apple's documentation.'reloadData' takes care of the rest.
         One thing to note is that the logic for setting the cells content should see to it that whenever reload data is called, the cells get correct contents from the array.